# facebook graph api 2.6

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook development and I need some information to clarify the Rate Limit on calls to the Graph API. I am building an app that is not an Facebook application. It's a web application that is calling Graph API regularly to receive feeds, likes, comments from public pages Feeds, Facebook introduced API Limits and various calls limits to Graph API. In this context I have some questions:

1. What does Facebook mean when they say that you rate limit is calculated based on Logged In users. As I said, my app is not a Facebook app. It's an app that connects externally to Graph API and fetch some data.
2. Getting data from Graph API is considered "Automated Data Collection" in the sens of Facebook Policy? Or Automated Data Collection refers only to crawlers that get the information skipping Graph API?

Comment: Then you have no users. And Scraping is not allowed without written permission from Facebook so that you should not do

Comment: I received another answer on Facebook Developer Group. They said it is ok. Are you sure about your answer? If I authenticate the user in my web app using Facebook, it is considered that i have users?